# Particles/Hair: How do I adjust the normal so the spikes go the same way around the object?

Tags: particles, normals

Is there a way to adjust the up/rotation of a face's normal, so all the spikes flow the same way on the object

For some reason they seam to flip over when I apply this particle system to the simple cylinder and cube.

[image]

Hmmm, i've noticed that when using emitter as oppose to hair, then the normals dont flip round...

[image]
[image]

Except, curve to mesh, type objects, the normals twist around....

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of web digging and experimenting, the answer was in the manual!

In the Particles panel enable the Rotation option, and set Initial Orientation to Normal-Tangent. BUT you need to have created a UV map for this to work.

Depending on the shape of your faces, the UV Reset option in UV Mapping drop down can be useful setting the initial rotation too.